# How do I trigger an Angular validation directive to update when a value it is compared to changes?

Tags: angular

I have built some custom form validation directives that compare form fields to other properties. They work great when you change the value of the form field, the validation fires and updates the validity of the form field just fine.

The problem I have is when the property that I am comparing it to changes the form validation is not triggered and the form field being compared to the property doesn't change validity.

I have created an example stackblitz here.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t7h2ok

When you change the value of the the first field it is invalid if it is the same as the other field and valid if not. The problem is when I change the other field I would like to make sure that the validity of the first form field is updated when the other property is changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cleaner solution for anybody that might be interested is to implement OnChanges in your validator and add the following code.

```
onChange: () => void;

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if ('theNameOfYourPropertyToWatch' in changes)) {
        if (this.onChange) this.onChange();
    }
}

registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
}
```

I have implemented a ValidatorBase class for my validators that implements this. Here is a stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfexiy

Answer (score 3):

To answer my own question for anybody that might be interested.

While Powkachu's answer is one that I do use elsewhere, I have read that article before but my scenario in this instance requires that I am binding the validation attributes to properties with the [box] syntax and I cannot use attributes to represent a string for a control's name in this instance.

I took a reference to ngModel of the target input in a view variable

```
<input name="value" [(ngModel)]="value" [notEqual]="other" #valueModel="ngModel">
```

and now it is possible to trigger validation with a call to the control's updateValueAndValidity method.

```
<input name="other" [(ngModel)]="other" (change)="valueModel.control.updateValueAndValidity()">
```

Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fnsmz

Answer (score 2):

I used [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2) article to find a solution. I'm reusing some of its sentences.

First, put your directive on your other input too:

```
<input name="other" [(ngModel)]="other" notEqual="value">
```

Then add a new attribute called `reverse`.

```
<input name="other" [(ngModel)]="other" notEqual="value" reverse="true">
```

- When reverse is **false** or **not set**, we will perform notEqual validation.
- When reverse is **true**, we will still perform notEqual, but instead of adding errors to current control, we add errors to the target control.

Update your directive to use this new attribute:

```
...
import { Attribute } from '@angular/core';

constructor(
    @Attribute('notEqual') public notEqual: string,
    @Attribute('reverse') public reverse: string
  ) {}

private get isReverse()
{
  if (!this.reverse) return false;
    return this.reverse === 'true' ? true: false;
}

validate(c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any }
{
    // self value
    let v = c.value;

    // control value
    let e = c.root.get(this.notEqual);

    // value not equal
    if (e && v === e.value && !this.isReverse) {
        return {
          notEqual: false
        }
    }

    // value equal and reverse
    if (e && v !== e.value && this.isReverse) {
        if (e.errors !== null)
          delete e.errors['notEqual'];
        if (e.errors !== null && !Object.keys(e.errors).length)
          e.setErrors(null);
    }

    // value not equal and reverse
    if (e && v === e.value && this.isReverse) {
        e.setErrors({ notEqual: false });
    }

    return null;
}
```

To make this directive work, put the inputs into the same `<form>` tag. Finally, html file will look like this:

```
<form>
  Value: <input name="value" [(ngModel)]="value" notEqual="other"><br>
  Other: <input name="other" [(ngModel)]="other" notEqual="value" reverse="true">
</form>
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wctroz?file=src/app/not-equal.directive.ts) is the updated stackblitz.

Comment: I have read an article with the same solution on password again. The problem with that solution is that the other value needs to be updated via a form input, I used a form input in my stackblitz just as an easy way to update the property but I need a solution that watches a property that is not participating in the form.